# Rewrite rule for WebAPI fails because of ExtensionlessUrlHandler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain, url-rewriting

I am attempting to use IIS to rewrite requests from my ASP.net MVC 4 application to my ASP.net MVC 4 WebApi.  From the client, I am using ajax to make calls back to the server which I would then like the server to rewrite the request to point to the webapi site.  This should solve any cross domain issues if I can get it to work.

I have installed URL rewrite, Web Farm Framework, ARR, and External Cache per this article:  http://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/archive/2011/04/20/how-to-install-application-request-routing-arr-2-5-without-web-platform-installer-webpi.aspx

In IIS->Application Request Routing->Server Proxy Settings" and checked the box that says "Enable proxy".

My rewrite rule looks like:

```
<rule name="webapi" stopProcessing =" true" >
  < match url =" webapi/(.*)" />
  < conditions>
    < add input =" {HTTP_HOST}" pattern="web(\.mytest\.com)$" />
  </ conditions>
  < action type =" Rewrite" url= "http://api{C:1}/api/{R:1} " />
</ rule>
```

What is really curious if I remove the ExtensionlessUrlHandlers in the web.config of my MVC site, then my rewrite works perfectly.  Unfortunately, the MVC routing breaks and my site no longer works.  If put the ExtensionlessUrlHandlers back in, the rewrite fails and the MVC routing works as expected.

Is there a simple way to solve this issue?

Comment: I've been working with Microsoft support on this issue and it appears that there is a problem with how the Integrated App Pool Managed Pipeline handles the calls.  If you change it from Integrated to Classic, then the rewrite rule works.  I'm waiting to hear back from Microsoft support on how to get past having to change to Classic mode so that will work on platforms such as Azure without having to jump through a dozen hoops.

Comment: any updates on this? I was hoping to do the same thing