# iis7 asp.net mvc webapi rewrite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have the same problem as in the referenced post ([Rewrite rule for WebAPI fails because of ExtensionlessUrlHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885343/rewrite-rule-for-webapi-fails-because-of-extensionlessurlhandler)) and have tried several attempts to workaround the issue with some success.  What I am stuck at now is the following:

Background:

- IIS7, Rewrite Module and ARR (I am a newbie to rewrite & ARR)
- Site1 hosting my web front using ASP.Net MVC4 (www.foo.com)
- Site2 hosting my webapi using ASP.Net MVC4 (svc.foo.com)
- I have full control over the code & site configs for both sites

Goal:

- rewrite www.foo.com/svc/* to svc.foo.com/api/*

Working:

- www.foo.com/svc/somecontroller/0 successfully maps to svc.foo.com/api/somecontroller/0

Not Working:

- www.foo.com/svc/somecontroller?id=0
- I turned on Failed Request Tracking and it seems the rewrite module is rewritting the url but for some reason the request is never made to svc.foo.com

Details:

- To workaround the issue in the referenced post I append a ".s" to the end of every call to a webapi (I have full control so I can do this - not ideal but I need this working so okay for now)
- Without QS: www.foo.com/svc/somecontroller/0 becomes www.foo.com/svc/somecontroller.s
- With QS: www.foo.com/svc/somecontroller?id=0 becomes www.foo.com/svc/somecontroller?id=0.s
- I then use rewrite rules to strip the ".s" and make the real call to svc.foo.com/api/somecontroller/0 or svc.foo.com/api/somecontroller?id=0

I can't for the life of me figure out why when the querystring format is used this doesn't work.

Rewrite Rules:

```
< rule name="Route requests with QS" stopProcessing="true">
    < match url="^svc/(.*)" />
    < conditions>
        < add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*).s" />
    < / conditions>
    < action type="Rewrite" url="http://svc.foo.com/api/{R:1}?{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
< / rule>
< rule name="Route the requests without QS" stopProcessing="true"> 
    < match url="^svc/(.*).s" /> 
    < conditions>
        < add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" /> 
    < / conditions> 
    < action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://svc.foo.com/api/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" /> 
< / rule>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I wanted to do the same thing

Comment: Would it be because the /0.s would be considered an extension while ?0.s is not an extension? therefore it goes through the extensionlessUrlHandler and fails as in referenced post?

Answer (score 0):

This post worked for me.
[ARR/URL Rewriter within a .net Web API application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667270/arr-url-rewriter-within-a-net-web-api-application?lq=1)

Adding the ignoreRoutes did the job perfectly.